# Netplan configuration issues

Tags: networking, netplan, router

i have issue configuring netplan on a ubuntu machine i want to use as a router. i previously used a centos docker where the configuration was in /etc/network interfaces. I tried to translate it to netplan but could not figure it out.
Here is my configuration:

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WoF7.png)

Can you guys help me with the netplan configuration please?

Comment: See `https://netplan.io/examples/`

Comment: was there for a long time before deciding to ask for help here.  Still could not figure it out

Comment: @AblayeBiteye Welcome to AskUbuntu. Better to include text copy instead of screenshot. So such data get indexed and easy to read for user with limited internet access.